# Display text to another class

Tags: java, android, button, android-intent, onclicklistener

I have a `showAddForm` button like the imej below in `Claims.java`.

[image]

When the + `button` is pressed, it will show `Alert Dialog Window` with `radio buttons`. When the `radio button` is checked, it will goes to specific activity. In the activity, it has an editText and a `save` button. I want the value on the editText display on the `showAddForm` `button` when the `save` button in the activity is clicked. How can I do to achieve this?

**Claims.java**

```
 public class Claims extends Fragment {
    private TextView c;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View claims = inflater.inflate(R.layout.claims, container, false);


        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialogRadio();

            }
        };
        Button button1 = (Button) claims.findViewById(R.id.button10);
        Button button = (Button) claims.findViewById(R.id.button8);
        button1.setOnClickListener(listener);
         c=(TextView)claims.findViewById(R.id.textView49);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), CameraMain.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return claims;
    }

    public void AlertDialogRadio() {
        final CharSequence[] ClaimsModel = {"Project", "Petrol", "Car Maintenance"
                , "Medical", "Other"};

        AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alt_bld.setTitle("Select a Claims");
        alt_bld.setSingleChoiceItems(ClaimsModel, -1, new DialogInterface
                .OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (item == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Project1.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (item == 1) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Petrol.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (item == 2) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), CarMainten.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (item == 3) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Medical.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (item == 4) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Other.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
        alert.show();


    }
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                String result=data.getStringExtra("text");
                c.setText(result);


            }
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Write your code if there's no result
            }
        }
    }//onActivityResult
}
```

Assume the user choose Project.

**Project1.java**

```
  public class Project1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static String text;
    private static EditText txt;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.project);
       txt= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText36);
        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button17);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                text = txt.getText().toString();
                returnIntent.putExtra("text", text);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Now when I click `save` button in `Project1.java`, it return to the `AlertDialogRadio` which is not I want and the text still not displaying on the textView!!! **ANYONE CAN HELP?????**

Comment: Where is `showAddForm` form ?

Comment: It just a name actually. And I refer from http://mrbool.com/how-to-insert-data-into-a-sqlite-database-in-android/28895

Comment: Sure i will try to help but please explain more about issue

Comment: have a look at startActivityForResult()!.

Comment: ok, I just simplify my issue. How to display the value from Project1.java editText to textView in Claims.java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `startActivityForResult()` and override `onActivityResult()` in your activity. You can use `setResult()` in the second activity to pass whatever you want to your caller activity.

Example [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

---

edit:

If you want it to use from a Fragment, you have to write this in your Activity that is holding the Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

This will pass the result to your fragment, so you can handle the result inside your fragment.

And as I already mentioned, you have to use `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()`

Answer (score 0):

as @keybee  said you should use startActivityForResult() to start the project.class from your dialog.
In the Project1.Class when you click save use `setResult()` to send the value back to the claims.class(Dont do `startActivity()` again. just use `finish()` ).

and in your Claims.class use `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` to recieve the value sent from the project1.class.
you can do a setText() on showAddForm button in the  `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` function

Comment: I want it return to Claims.java, not AlertDialogRadio ...how can I do it?